# pandas apply function on multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to apply a function on a multiindex dataframe (basically groupby describe dataframe) without using for loop to traverse level 0 index.

Function I'd like to apply:

```
def CI(x):
    import math
    sigma = x["std"]
    n = x["count"]
    return 1.96 * sigma / math.sqrt(n)
```

Sample of my dataframe:

```
df = df.iloc[47:52, [3,4,-1]]

               a          b                    id
47          0.218182   0.000000  0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568
48          0.000000   0.000000  0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568
49          0.218182   0.130909  0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568
50          0.000000   0.000000  0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432
51          0.000000   0.000000  0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432
```

And I replace zeros with nan:

```
df = df.replace(float(0), np.nan)
```

Groupy on id and describe and I get multiindex:

```
df_group = df.groupby("id").describe()
```

Current solution I don't like and think could be improved:

```
l_df = []
for column in df_group.columns.levels[0]:
    df = pd.DataFrame({"CI" : df_group[column].apply(CI, axis = 1)})
    l_df.append(df)
CI = pd.concat(l_df, axis = 1)
CI.columns = df_group.columns.levels[0]
```

so I get something like:

```
                                    a       b
id
06f32e6e45da385834dac983256d59f3    nan     nan
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568    0.005   0.225
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432    0.008   nan
11e0057cdc8b8e1b1cdabfa8a092ea5f    0.018   0.582
120549af6977623bd01d77135a91a523    0.008   0.204
```

So again, if I have top level columns from a to z, and each contains std and count column, how can I apply my function to each of these columns at the same time?

Comment: Thank you John for reply. It's shorter solution, but in principle it's just rephrasing my solution. I wanted to know if there is a method within pandas that could operate on multiindex level, without for loops or list comprehensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `groupby` on `level` with `axis=1`, let's you iterate and apply over the first level columns.

```
In [104]: (df.groupby("id").describe()
             .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
             .apply(lambda x: x[x.name].apply(CI, axis=1)))
Out[104]:
                                    a   b
id
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568  0.0 NaN
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432  NaN NaN
```

Infact, you don't need `CI`, if you were to

```
In [105]: (df.groupby("id").describe()
             .groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[x.name]
             .apply(lambda x: 1.96*x['std']/np.sqrt(x['count']), axis=1)))
Out[105]:
                                    a   b
id
0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568  0.0 NaN
0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432  NaN NaN
```

Sample `df`

```
In [106]: df
Out[106]:
           a         b                                id
47  0.218182       NaN  0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568
48       NaN       NaN  0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568
49  0.218182  0.130909  0d1974107c6731989c762e96def73568
50       NaN       NaN  0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432
51       NaN       NaN  0fd4f3b4adf43682f08e693a905b7432
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. May I ask how are you printing results to stackoverflow, because when I tried to copy from jupyter notebook formatting was messed up and I had to do quite a few corrections by hand.

Comment: Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples