# Shifting column in multiindex dataframe with missting dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, missing-data, multi-index

I'd like to shift a column in a multiindex dataframe in order to calculate a regression model with a lagged independent variable. As my time-series has missing values I only want to have the values shifted for known previous days. The df looks like that:

```
                cost
ID  day
1   31.01.2020  0
1   03.02.2020  0
1   04.02.2020  0.12
1   05.02.2020  0
1   06.02.2020  0
1   07.02.2020  0.08
1   10.02.2020  0
1   11.02.2020  0
1   12.02.2020  0.03
1   13.02.2020  0.1
1   14.02.2020  0
```

The desired output would like that:

```
                cost   cost_lag
ID  day
1   31.01.2020  0      NaN
1   03.02.2020  0      NaN
1   04.02.2020  0.12   0
1   05.02.2020  0      0.12
1   06.02.2020  0      0
1   07.02.2020  0.08   0
1   10.02.2020  0      NaN
1   11.02.2020  0      0
1   12.02.2020  0.03   0
1   13.02.2020  0.1    0.03
1   14.02.2020  0      0.1
```

Based on [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28997816/12934163) I've tried the following:

```
df['cost_lag'] = df.groupby(['id'])['cost'].shift(1)[df.reset_index().day == df.reset_index().day.shift(1) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)]
```

But that results in an error message I don't understand:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

I've also tried to fill the missing dates following an approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114844/12934163):

```
ams_spend_ranking_df = ams_spend_ranking_df.index.get_level_values(1).apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x, 1, 1))
```

again resulting in an error message which does not enlighten me:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

**Long story short**: how can I shift the cost column by 1 day and add NaNs if I don't have data on the previous day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all missing datetimes by [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) with [`Resampler.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.asfreq.html):

```
df1 = df.reset_index(level=0).groupby(['ID'])['cost'].resample('d').asfreq()
print (df1)
ID  day       
1   2020-01-31    0.00
    2020-02-01     NaN
    2020-02-02     NaN
    2020-02-03    0.00
    2020-02-04    0.12
    2020-02-05    0.00
    2020-02-06    0.00
    2020-02-07    0.08
    2020-02-08     NaN
    2020-02-09     NaN
    2020-02-10    0.00
    2020-02-11    0.00
    2020-02-12    0.03
    2020-02-13    0.10
    2020-02-14    0.00
Name: cost, dtype: float64
```

So then if use your solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) it working like need:

```
df['cost_lag'] = df1.groupby('ID').shift(1)
print (df)
               cost  cost_lag
ID day                       
1  2020-01-31  0.00       NaN
   2020-02-03  0.00       NaN
   2020-02-04  0.12      0.00
   2020-02-05  0.00      0.12
   2020-02-06  0.00      0.00
   2020-02-07  0.08      0.00
   2020-02-10  0.00       NaN
   2020-02-11  0.00      0.00
   2020-02-12  0.03      0.00
   2020-02-13  0.10      0.03
   2020-02-14  0.00      0.10
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Unfortunately that results in some strange behavior like the following: `   cost cost_lag
ID day
3  2020-03-23 0,11 0
3 2020-03-24 0 0,11
3 2020-03-25 0 0
3 2020-03-26 0,14 0
3 2020-03-28 0,14 0,14
3 2020-03-29 0,15 0,14
3 2020-03-30 0 0,15
3 2020-04-01 0 0,13 `

Comment: @TiTo - problem with real data? Or with sample?

Comment: @TiTo - what is your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas version is 0.24.2

Comment: @TiTo - Tested in pandas 1.0.1

Comment: Ok I'll update my pandas version and try it again. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214100/discussion-between-tito-and-jezrael).